# Unload Item From Data Context's Local View

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I'm loading notes from a database to bind them to a WPF control, like such:

```
this.DBContext.Notes.Where(n => n.ID == selectedNote.ID).Load();
this.notesBox.DataContext = this.DBContext.Notes.Local;
```

If I want to remove an item from the Local View...

```
this.DBContext.Local.Notes.Remove(selectedNote);
this.notesBox.DataContext = this.DBContext.Notes.Local;
```

...it no longer displays in notesBox, BUT then if I select the note again I can no longer load it into the Local View.

**Question: Given that .Load() loads a set of data into the Local View, what is the proper way to unload them from the Local View, so that I can re-load them back in later on?**

(I'm assuming that Local.Remove(entity) actually deletes the item from the database if I were to run DBContext.SaveChanges() and that's the reason why I'm not able to load it back in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct in that removing from local will also remove it from the DbSet so it's being deleted from the database.

If you're wanting to modify a collection that's not going to result in changes to your database, you should create a new observable collection off of your Notes query and bind to it:

```
var collection = new ObservableCollection<Note>(this.DBContext.Notes.Where(n => n.ID == selectedNote.ID)); 
this.notesBox.DataContext = collection;
```

This way you can remove/modify your new collection without modifying the database.

Comment: Wow... I must have been so obsessed over using the "official" Local View that I didn't even think of creating my own local view. Thanks!